# C# huge performance drop assigning float value

Tags: c#, performance

I am trying to optimize my code and was running VS performance monitor on it.

[image]

It shows that simple assignment of float takes up a major chunk of computing power?? I don't understand how is that possible.

Here is the code for TagData:

```
public class TagData
{
    public int tf;
    public float tf_idf;
}
```

So all I am really doing is:

```
float tag_tfidf = td.tf_idf;
```

I am confused.

Comment: Do all of the percentages add up to 100%? I ask because it looks like I can't see them all. Is it possible that the statement you're asking about is just a heavy load in comparison to the rest of the routine?

Comment: Are you using trace-based line-by-line profiling? I prefer sampling because it is unbiased.

Comment: @kehrk It still seems odd that a floating point assignment would be a larger hit than the next line, which is a floating point multiplication *and* a floating point assignment. I think Nate's suggestion of lazy enumeration is probably a more likely scenario.

Comment: Play a little with the code and move stuff around. This is probably an imprecision somewhere or a bug. To prove that theory, play with variations of the code. Probably you can make the behavior disappear. Simple floating point ops, especially assignments, should not drain too much performance. They are quite fast.

Comment: How long does the entire method take to execute? I suppose that it is a very short time and therefore the measured data is not accurate.

Comment: Is this 32 or 64-bit architecture?  (OS etc might be good to know too)

Comment: Whatever profiler you use: Use a different one. It can only become better. To get real numbers try Windows Performance Toolkit which has also a sampling profiler under its belt. To check which line was hot you need to attach a debugger after the profiling to check which address was hot to get line level timing back.

Comment: What is the total execution time of this code? How many words and how many tags? If The total number of inner iterations is not in the thousands, you're probably just measuring noise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll post another theory: it might be the cache miss of the first access to members of `td`. A memory load takes 100-200 cycles which in this case seems to amount to about 1/3 of the total duration of the method.

Points to test this theory:

1. Is your data set big? It bet it is.
2. Are you accessing the `TagData`'s in random memory order? I bet they are not sequential in memory. This causes the memory prefetcher of the CPU to be dysfunctional.
3. Add a new line `int dummy = td.tf;` before the expensive line. This new line will now be the most expensive line because it will trigger the cache miss. Find some way to do a dummy load operation that the JIT does not optimize out. Maybe add all `td.tf` values to a local and pass that value to `GC.KeepAlive` at the end of the method. That should keep the memory load in the JIT-emitted x86.

I might be wrong but contrary to the other theories so far mine is **testable**.

Try making `TagData` a `struct`. That will make all items of `term.tags` sequential in memory and give you a nice performance boost.

Comment: Once either value is read out of td, it'll likely be faster for the rest, especially if the compiler is smart enough to realize more than one field is being read.  PS - Couldn't the loop just be run twice in a row for same data?  PPS - probably both unaligned *and* a miss.  Wish he'd answer about architecture.

Comment: @ebyrob yes that would be another good way to test. Running the inner loop twice should give far less than twice the running time. (As long as the CPU cache can hold all of `term.tags`, of course).

Comment: I don't know how good the profiler is, but even if it only held 50% (or 15%) there would be a boost for N% of the cycles.  (and clynch your theory in one go)

Comment: indeed once I made TagData a struct, its execution time dropped tremendously.

Comment: I figured out that the problem is that there are few billion calls to this function that's why its so slow. While turning it to struct significantly reduced the process speed, its still way too slow, and I need to think of some way of limiting my term-tag collection. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using LINQ? If so, LINQ uses lazy enumeration so the first time you access the value you pulled out, it's going to be painful.

If you are using LINQ, call ToList() after your query to only pay the price once.

It also looks like your data structure is sub optimal but since I don't have access to your source (and probably couldn't help even if I did :) ), I can't tell you what would be better.

EDIT: As commenters have pointed out, LINQ may not be to blame; however my question is based on the fact that both foreach statements are using IEnumerable.  The TagData assignment is a pointer to the item in the collection of the IEnumerable (which may or may not have been enumerated yet).  The first access of legitimate data is the line that pulls the property from the object.  The first time this happens, it may be executing the entire LINQ statement and since profiling uses the average, it may be off.  The same can be said for tagScores (which I'm guessing is database backed) whose first access is really slow and then speeds up.  I wasn't pointing out the solution just a possible problem given my understanding of IEnumerable.

See http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/10/01/lazy-linq-and-enumerable-objects.aspx

Comment: How could LINQ even conceivably be relevent to the code the OP posted?

Comment: @KirkWoll He's looping through collections, it seems like. So I'd call it a bit edgy to go around shouting "INCONCEIVABLE!"

Comment: A read of a field is not lazy, ever. The lazynes must occur at a different point in the method. Clever idea, but this is not it.

Comment: @Nate - sorry, I `-1`'d this, as the question does not mention LINQ, and "Are you using LINQ?" is a great clarifying comment to add to the original post.

Comment: +1 because I found your edit useful and interesting, even though LINQ isn't a factor in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see that next line to the suspicious one takes only `0.6` i.e

```
float tag_tfidf = td.tf_idf;//29.6
string tagName =...;//0.6
```

I suspect this is caused bu the excessive number of calls, and also note `float` is a value type, meaning they are copied by value. So everytime you assign it, runtime creates new `float` (Single) struct and initializes it by copying the value from `td.tf_idf` which takes huge time.

You can see `string tagName =...;` doesn't takes much because it is copied by reference.

Edit: As comments pointed out I may be wrong in that respect, this might be a bug in profiler also, Try re profiling and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Copying a float is a single low cycle-count machine instruction. `Single` is a runtime intrinsic. Is is dirt cheap, as it is in C.

Comment: I would expect that copying a float which has 32 bits and copying a reference which has 32 or 64 bits to take approximately the same time.

Comment: One of the next operations is multiplication of two floats and it takes only 2.3%, this is ten times less than simple assignment of float. Your theory is wrong.

Comment: @usr Is `Single` dirt-cheap on 64-bit modern architecture?  How's that struct's alignment too?  float comes *after* 32 bits of int.  Note the "next float op" isn't reading the second-half of a 64-bit struct which isn't properly aligned to 64-bits.

Comment: Single is 32 bits and the CLR aligns all members to natural boundaries. Floats are really not that expensive.

Comment: @usr so just to be clear, assuming 64-bit the struct is 128 bits with { 0: int32 (32bitsempty), 64: float32 (32bitsempty) } ?  And this can't be configured differently by the developer?  (Obviously I'm talking about the cost of an un-aligned read, not of a float really)

Comment: Ok if it was unaligned your comment makes perfect sense. If I had downvoted I would now reset the vote. The memory layout looks like this on any bitness (in this case): { 0: int32, 32: float32 }. Members are aligned to *their* natural size, not to `IntPtr.Size` bytes. This is configurable using StructLayout but that's `unsafe`.